# Bootstrap navbar links and nav brand centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]I would like to be my navigation structure the nav brand image(logo) should be center top, after that my navigation should be center aligned.
Simply brand logo and nav bar links should be center but both should be different lines and sticky. Tried in below way But I am unable to get it.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>    
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Left</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#about">Right</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Right</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center, .navbar-header-center {
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header navbar-header-center">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>    
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
           <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
           <li><a href="#about">Left</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">Right</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Right</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Added ref image I want navigation in that format

Comment: i edited my answer.... it should now look like your image. Please set answer to correct if you like it ;)

Comment: Gr8! but small issue why resposnive is not working, clicking on button(hamburger menu in mobile) menu is not showing.

Comment: yes because the javascript was missing (i thought you know that because you didn´t add it to your answer) you have to include jQuery and Bootstrap javascript. But make sure jQuery is inserted before Bootstrap ... otherwise Bootstrap is not working. I added a sample in my snipet ;)

Comment: yeah! I have added it, working fine thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>    
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Left</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#about">Right</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Right</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

    <style>
    .navbar-header {
    float: none;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
}
.navbar-collapse {
display: inline-block !important;
text-align:center;
width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-left, .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
float:none !important;
display:inline-block;
}
    </style>
```

Comment: Solution is gr8! but resposnive is not working, could you please check from mobile side menu is not collapsable.

Comment: use media queries for mobile. just revert back the original css properties and add bootstrap javascript plugin to make the hamburger menu work.

Comment: yup I have missed to add js files, thanks for your solution.

Comment: While adding too many links those are wrapping up to next line, is there anyway to make center aligned with as many as links and no need to consider nav-left and nav-right you can ignore them.